# webapi - dbcontext injection into fluentvalidation validator

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac, fluentvalidation

Hello I am having a hard time passing an HTTP scoped object into a fluent validation validator.  Everything works until I try to inject a service and then it throws the following error

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the
>   scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates
>   that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by
>   a SingleInstance() component

It comes down to the below snippet I think and I don't know how to mimic it in webapi

```
 public Func<T> HttpRequestScopedFactoryFor<T>(){
       return () => system.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<T>();
  }
```

IN MVC my autofac code looked like so

```
    public class FluentValidationModule : Module
    {
                public Func<T> HttpRequestScopedFactoryFor<T>()
                {
                    return () => System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<T>();
                }

                protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
                {
                    base.Load(builder);
                    builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
                    builder.RegisterInstance(HttpRequestScopedFactoryFor<ApplicationDbContext>());
                }
        }
     }
```

My FluentValidation  validator code looked like so

```
public class RoleDTOValidator : AbstractValidator<RoleDTO>
    {
        readonly Func<ApplicationDbContext> _dbFactory;
        public RoleDTOValidator(Func<ApplicationDbContext> dbFactory)
        {
            _dbFactory = dbFactory;
            RuleFor(m => m.Id).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(m => m.Name).NotEmpty().Must(DoesNotExist).WithMessage("Another permission exists with that name."); ;
            RuleFor(m => m.Description).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(m => m.Permissions).NotEmpty().SetCollectionValidator(new ApplicationRoleClaimValidator());
        }

        bool DoesNotExist(RoleDTO model, string name)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = _dbFactory();
            int count = db.Roles.Count(item => item.Name == name);
            return count == 0;
        }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you resolve like this in factory for web api. `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService<T>` also be sure you have configured as like [this](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#quick-start)

Comment: I did try that and it did not work for me, complained about a null reference